# Incrementally Growing a Tuple

Tags: c++, boost-hana

Say I want to incrementally collect data in a tuple (or an equivalent heterogeneous container), i.e. incrementally add another value (and type) to the tuple.

Something along these lines (names and syntax are made up):

```
growable_tuple tup;
tup.push_back(42);
//...
tup.push_back("Hello");
//...
tup.push_back(' ');
//...
tup.push_back("World"s);

static_assert(4 == std::tuple_size<tup::type>::value); // or
assert(4 == tup.size());
```

I could use `std::tuple_cat` but I would need to copy and store the result in a different local variable for each such `cat`.

I can’t use `std::any` since I won’t know the contained type.
Is there such a way to extract the contained type of an `any`?

Is it possible to have a *single* local variable that supports such "insert"s preferably without copying?

Does Hana have such a facility?

Basically, I want a heterogeneous container that does not erase the types so that they can be accessed later.
I can also assume that the inserts are not runtime dependent (no runtime loops inserting).
Specifically, I could manually go over the code noting all the types (and index) added to the tuple and use this to define my initial tuple. All the data exists at compile time.
I am wondering if there is no way to do this without manually specifying the tuple type beforehand.

One obvious way to do this is to incrementally serialize the data (e.g. to json) and reparse it later, but this seems a bit roundabout.

Comment: If the set of expected types is known beforehand, you can use a container of `std::variant` objects.

Comment: Can you illustrate what you want with some pseudocode?

Comment: @Leon: No, I need a tuple and I don't know the types beforehand. I'll add an example.

Comment: `static_assert(4 == std::tuple_size<tup::type>::value);` No way this will work when you don't know the types before compilation...And then you could just use `std::tuple`

Comment: @SimonKraemer: well, I said the syntax is made up.

Comment: It's not about syntax, it's about available information. The number of elements in your `growable_tuple` and their types are not known at compile time which is required for `static_assert` to work.

Comment: @SimonKraemer: See my edits above, assume all the info is potentially available at compile time.

Comment: I don't think I understand why `std::tuple_cat` isn't good for you. Could you elaborate on this a bit more? In particular consider if move semantics couldn't be helpful...(?)

Comment: @W.F.: It's more about clutter, you need multiple local objects to store the increasingly growing tuple - each one with one extra entry. Also, I am not sure about moving, since it would mean you have a lot of moved from objects in the scope that you must not touch.

Comment: @AdiShavit OK I got your point now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Amazingly, this *is* apparently possible.

See [HOW TO IMPLEMENT A COMPILE-TIME META-CONTAINER IN C++](http://b.atch.se/posts/constexpr-meta-container/) and related articles. With a bit more syntactic sugar it should be able to give the functionality of the OP.

An example of [working code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6aea3ce01fb531d9) looks like this:

```
int main () {
  using LX = atch::meta_list<class A>;

  LX::push<void, void, void, void> ();
  LX::set<0, class Hello> ();
  LX::set<2, class World> ();
  LX::pop ();

  print_type<LX::value<>> ();
}
```

with the output:
`void print_type() [T = atch::type_list<Hello, void, World>]`

This is even more powerful than just appending a type to a list.
I look fwd to the eventual release of the `smeta` library.

An [additional post](https://tartanllama.github.io/c++/2016/07/28/integral_variable/) on the technique is here.

Answer (score 0):

A tuple is a class, just like any other class. Once declared, it is that class forever. A

```
std::tuple<int, char *>
```

once declared, will always be a `std::tuple<int, char *>`. C++ is a statically typed language. The type of each object is declared, and is known. Once an object is a `std::tuple<int, char *>` that's what it's going to be, it cannot somehow become a `std::tuple<int, char *, char *>`

With C++17, it's possible to achieve something like this by using a

```
std::vector<std::any>
```

that is, a vector of `any` objects, and then add arbirary objects to the vector. The type of this object will always be `std::vector<std::any>`, and additional work will be needed to figure out what each value of the vector is.

Comment: Yes, I know all this, and hence the OP.    
All the information is known at compile time, so I am wondering if e.g. Hana has some type erasure (and unerasure) magic to allow this.

Comment: There is no magic that can alter the fundamental fact that C++ is a statically typed language. It is what it is, and neither hana, no any other library can change this. This goes to the fundamental concept of what C++ is all about. The only thing that can be done is the `std::any` approach. That's all you can do.